# Getting multiple Instances of key using bsearch()

Tags: c++, bsearch

is there a way to implement `bsearch()` to find multiple instances of key.

for example: `(obj*)bsearch(key=r,arr,elements,sizeof(obj),(int(*)(const void*, const void*)bcompare);`

The code I currently wrote only finds the first instance and cannot proceed past the first found due to how it works.

```
getline(target,81);
if(strcmp(target,"exit") == 0 || strcmp(target, "") == 0) break;
p = (Info*)bsearch(target,list,num,sizeof(Info),(int(*)(const void*, const void*))bcompare);
int foundIndex = (int)(p-list);
if(!p){
    err_dis1_win();
    clrscr();
}
else{
    display_record(p);
    cout << "\n\n found at index " << foundIndex << "\n";
    getch();
    clrscr();   
}
```

**Variables:**

- **p** - is a pointer to object of class Info
- **target** - arr of char
- **list** - arr of obj
- **foundIndex** - index of element found
- **Info** - derived class from base class

**compare function

```
int bcompare(char *a,Info *b){
    return(strncmpi(a, b -> get_name(), strlen(a)));
}
```

I cannot use other methods such as `std::find` or writing my own binary search function and have to use `bsearch()`

I have tried loops inside the else block, and the compare function using the varible foundIndex, as well as using a while loop on the return value looping through the obj list arr. Is there a way to start at a specific index. I appreciate any help. I am not looking for code but a general push in the right direction. Thank you.

**Caveat** - The current code compiles and runs as expected however, the functionality that I want, cannot be figured out by myself. Google and search on Stackoverflow has not produced an related issue.

Comment: Since you added two different language tags: Do you need an answer for C, C++, or both?

Comment: Classically (for the binary search algorithm in general, and C's library `bsearch()` in particular) if there are multiple keys, you just get one of them.  Guaranteeing a return of the first, or providing a way to return all of them, is an interesting variant.  I implemented it myself once; I don't remember how much work it was.  If you want to return all, you obviously need a different calling interface.

Comment: @usr2564301 - Both languages would be great as I am familiarizing myself with both due to this is compiled through borland 5.5 unfortunately.

Comment: @Steve Summit - Figured as much but restrictions of implementation apply. Whereas I cannot use my own compare method otherwise I would of wrote a different one and iterate through the arr for each element.

Comment: As `bsearch` may return any key inside a contiguous segment of same-keys, use it and then decrease the found index while the previous key is the same.

Comment: I'm confused.  On one hand, you ask "is there a way to *implement* `bsearch`", but on the other you say you cannot write your own binary search function.  Do you then really mean to ask how you can *use* the standard library's `bsearch()` for your purpose?  And if you must not write your own method, then does that mean you need `bsearch` to return a value that you can use directly as, say, the index of the first matching key?

Comment: @JohnBollinger - yes the std librarys bsearch function, as stated in the caveat this runs returning only the first found index which is what bsearch does. To clarify I was wondering is there a implementation to find concurrent matching elements in the sorted array after the first element is found.

Comment: @usr2564301 - How would i go about implementing that? "use it and then decrease the found index while the previous key is the same" -usr2564301

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `bsearch()` returns only one item, I interpret "find multiple instances of key" as "find *the first* instance of a key".  The caller can then step forward through the array from that item to process each item matching the key, until it reaches the end or reaches an item that does not match.

If you must use the standard library's `bsearch()` function and persuade it to find the first item matching a given key, then all you really have to work with is the comparison function you present.  `bsearch()` will return an item that matches the key according to that function, but if more than one item matches then there is no guarantee which one will be returned.  You must ensure, then, that only the item you want matches.

You can approach that with an appropriate implementation of the comparison function, but there is a significant problem.  The function will in some cases need to evaluate the item preceding the one specified to it, but it must not attempt to examine an item preceding the array's first.  `bsearch()` does not itself convey any information about the array bounds to the comparison function.

There are at least two possible solutions, neither of them stellar.

1. **Store the array lower bound in some well-known location that the function can access.**  For example, if the comparison function is a static member function, then maybe you would use a static variable of its class.  But that is not thread-safe.  You could do something similar with thread-local variables, but even then it's ugly.  Either way, you have to be sure to set that variable appropriately before you call `bsearch()`, and that's ugly, too.

***OR***

2. **Ensure that you never `bsearch()` for the first item.**  One way you could do that would be by checking preliminarily whether the first item matches (but not via the comparison function), and using it directly instead of calling `bsearch()` in the event that it does match.  I'd wrap that in a method, myself, and if you must not do so then requiring that such a calling discipline be employed manually is also ugly.

Having chosen one of the above, you can implement a comparison function that looks at the previous item's key in addition to the specified item's.  Something along these lines (which assumes the second alternative):

```
struct my_item {
    int key;
    void *data;
};

// bsearch() passes the target item as the first argument, and the one to compare
// to it as the second
int compare_items(const void *to_find, const void *to_check) {
    const struct my_item *to_find_item = (const struct my_item *) to_find;
    const struct my_item *to_check_item = (const struct my_item *) to_check;

    // Check first how the key members are ordered
    if (to_find_item->key < to_check_item->key) {
        return -1;
    } else if (to_find_item->key > to_check_item->key) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        // The key members match, so check whether we're looking at the first
        // such item.
        const struct my_item *previous_item = to_check_item - 1;

        // If the previous item's key does match, then we know the item we're
        // looking for is an earlier one than we are presently checking.
        return (previous_item->key == to_check_item->key) ? -1 : 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I actually figured it out by adding temp variables/ arr-file stream. I then copied the contents of the first stream to the second and then passed that from the first found index to a function that repeated the process. This essentially cut the array to nothing satisfying the while condition. Which then exited the sub-menu zeroing out all temp variable values as to reuse the variables for the following cases. I appreciate the help and knowledge. I however am going to mark your answer as It gave me the idea to do the above. Thanks Again!